# Complex number unknowns problem

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help to solve this problem:

**Find two complex numbers that add up to 1+4i, their quotient is purely imaginary and the real part of one of them is -1**

I've tried to start the exercise, but I honestly have no clue:

z + (1+4i) = -1 +ai

I also do not understand why in one of the solutions given by the lecturer is z = 2 + i (2- sqrt(2)) since the exercise says the real part must be -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$. You want to have

- $(a+bi)+(c+di)=1+4i$;
- $\frac{a+bi}{c+di}$ is purely imaginary;
- $a=-1$ or $c=-1$.

From the first condition, you deduce that $c=1-a$ and that $d=4-b$. Therefore\begin{align}\frac{a+bi}{c+di}&=\frac{a+bi}{1-a+(4-b)i}\\&=\frac{a(1-a)+b(4-b)+\bigl(-a(4-b)+b(1-a)\bigr)i}{(1-a)^2+(4-b)^2}\end{align}Now, if $a=-1$, this last expression becomes$$\frac{-2+b(4-b)+(4+b)i}{(4-b)^2}.$$Since you want this number to be purely imaginary, you must take $b$ such that $b(4-b)=2$; take $b=2+\sqrt2$, for instance. So, one answer to your problem is: take the numbers $-1+(2+\sqrt2)i$ and $2+(2-\sqrt2)i$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I do not understand why you state that a = 1 or c = 1

Comment: @Evoked My mistake. I meant $-1$.

Comment: Oh, know I see. Thank you for your help and your time! @José Carlos Santos

Answer (score 0):

$(a+bi)+(c+di)=1+4i\to a+c=1;\; c+d=4$

the quotient is imaginary

$$\frac{a+bi}{c+di}=\frac{a c+b d}{c^2+d^2}+\frac{b c-a d}{c^2+d^2}\,i$$

Real part is zero

$ac+bd=0$

and $a=-1$

so we have the system

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a=-1 \\
 a+c=1 \\
 b+d=4 \\
 a c+b d=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

with two solutions

$(a = -1,b = 2-\sqrt{2},c = 2,d = 2+\sqrt{2}),(a = -1,b = 2+\sqrt{2},c = 2,d = 2-\sqrt{2})$

$z_1=-1+i(2-\sqrt{2});\;w_1=2+i(2+\sqrt{2})$

$z_1=-1+i(2+\sqrt{2});\;w_2=2+i(2-\sqrt{2})$

Comment: Ok, know I understand. Thank you so much @Raffaele !